# Find the correct GUID-CommandId combination for visual studio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm trying to write a simple VS extension that will show if a menu has a shortcut attached to it.

So when a user clicks on Edit->Undo from the menu, I'd like to show a message 'Ctrl + Z' so the user can start learning that shortcut. The issue I'm having is to identify the GUID and the corresponding command id. The below looks about right, but when I click on File->Close, the callback is not invoked.

```
CommandID menuCommandId = new CommandID(VSConstants.GUID_VSStandardCommandSet97, (int)VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.FileClose);
```

protected override void Initialize()
{

```
    Debug.WriteLine (string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Entering Initialize() of: {0}", this.ToString()));
    base.Initialize();

    // Add our command handlers for menu (commands must exist in the .vsct file)
    var mcs = GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
    if ( null != mcs )
    {
        // Create the command for the menu item.

        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc826118%28v=vs.120%29.aspx
        CommandID menuCommandId = new CommandID(GuidList.guidLearnShortcutsCmdSet, (int)PkgCmdIDList.cmdIdLearnShortcuts);

        //workbench.files.action.closeFile
        //CommandID menuCommandId = new CommandID(VSConstants.GUID_VSStandardCommandSet97, (int)VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.FileClose);
        MenuCommand menuItem = new MenuCommand(MenuItemCallback, menuCommandId );
        mcs.AddCommand( menuItem );
    }
}

    private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IVsStatusbar statusBar = (IVsStatusbar)GetService(typeof(SVsStatusbar));

            MenuCommand btn = (MenuCommand)sender;

            // Make sure the status bar is not frozen
            int frozen;

            statusBar.IsFrozen(out frozen);

            if (frozen != 0)
            {
                statusBar.FreezeOutput(0);
            }

            // Set the status bar text and make its display static.
            statusBar.SetText("Update here.");

            // Freeze the status bar.
            statusBar.FreezeOutput(1);

            // Get the status bar text. 
            string text;
            statusBar.GetText(out text);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(text);

            // Clear the status bar text.
            statusBar.FreezeOutput(0);

        }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you're hooking into the click events on File -> Close or other menu items?

Comment: @@Colin Zabransky - plz let me know if you need some other part of the project.

Comment: @Arun, what do you mean by 'identify the GUID and id'. You want to capture the executed command's id and its group GUID, right?

Comment: @NValchev, that's right.

Comment: I think your issue is with this
    VSConstants.GUID_VSStandardCommandSet97

I don't think this would work, is your command null after?
I think you are going to need to find all of the individual command guids and attach each of them separately ,I don't think you can do a one shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable VSIPLogging in the registry, version num should be highest you have or the one you use.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\[version num]\General\EnableVSIPLogging = 1
```

then click on the toolbar or menu you want identify while keeping CTRL+SHIFT pressed. This will show a dialog with the command bar properties. Take note of the Guid and the CmdID

OLD article but it still works
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dr._ex/2007/04/17/using-enablevsiplogging-to-identify-menus-and-commands-with-vs-2005-sp1/

Comment: Thanks @Paul for the answer.